# Capybara::ExpectationNotMet

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

My feature file is like:

```
  Scenario: I am on dashboard area
    Given I am on dashboard
    Then I should see link 'All Cases'
    When I click on 'All Cases'
    Then I should see be redirected to case index page
```

And my step definition file is like:

```
Given(/^I am on dashboard$/) do
  visit dashboard_path
end

Then(/^I should see link 'All Cases'$/) do
  page.should have_content('All Cases')
end
```

For the cases I am getting the error : (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

All Cases is just the link in the sidebar.

Can some one please suggest me regarding this error... Tried a lot but its not working...

Comment: It would help if you gave the full error (ie it is not clear where the test is failing).

Answer (score 0):

the statement page.should have_content('All Cases') only matches that the text "All Cases" is on the page the link may have the name "all_cases_link" and no text on the page will match even though it may be on the page.  Try page.should have_link('All Cases') instead.

Comment: I wrote page.should have_link('All Cases') but still the error is coming as:                                                                  
  features/step_definitions/case_steps.rb:9
    Then I should see link 'All Cases'                       # features/step_definitions/case_steps.rb:13
      expected to find link "All Cases" but there were no matches (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
      ./features/step_definitions/case_steps.rb:20:in `/^I should see link 'All Cases'$/'